# Firebase order by key with numerical string keys

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I saw that the realtime database keys must be strings.
I want to use numbers as keys and do a start at and end at to fetch chunks of data e.g.

```
admin.database().ref('PARENT').orderByKey().startAt('107').endAt('1032').once('value');
```

will this do in numerical order e.g. 107,108,109,110,111,112... or will it return in a string order by e.g. 1,11,111,2,22,222

Thank you

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per post on Stack Overflow. You have two distinct issues here, so they should be two different posts.  I answered your first question, so please edit the question to remove it and ask it separately.

Comment: No problem I have added another question.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database keys are strings and should always be treated as such.

The exception to this happens with when fetching a parent node that that contains child nodes that *look like* mostly sequential numbers.  In that case, the client receives a list or array of results where the string keys actually become the numeric indexes on in the array.  However, it's generally [not recommended](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) to deal with lists of data this way (and I strongly recommend reading that linked blog post).  In particular, this part:

> If all of the keys are integers, and more than half of the keys between 0 and the maximum key in the object have non-empty values, then Firebase will render it as an array.

Comment: Would it be better to use the push() method and add a count propery (number) to each of the children. Then do a orderByChild('count') and add an index to the count property? Would this still provide a consistent order?

Comment: Yes, it's typically better to use push(), but you should also make sure that you include a child value that can be used to sort the children as required.  You can use that numeric child value to get a numeric sort.

Comment: Am i able to do a startAt EndAt type query on the children count property? or can this only be done on the keys()... (thats important for my feature)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Just give it a try, then post a new question along with the code that isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Keys are returned in lexicographical order, so you'll get 1,11,111,2,22,222.

If you want to get them in numerical order, use keys that sort the same lexicographically as they do numerically, by padding with 0's at the start:

```
{
  "001": { ... },
  "002": { ... },
  "011": { ... },
  "022": { ... },
  "111": { ... },
  "222": { ... }
}
```

The number of character you use should be picked to allow the maximum numeric value you ever want to support. In the above that maximum value would be 999, but you may have a different requirement and thus pick a different number of characters.

---

You can then also prefix the keys with a short non-numeric string, to ensure you never hit the array coercion that Doug mentions in his answer:

```
{
  "key001": { ... },
  "key002": { ... },
  "key011": { ... },
  "key022": { ... },
  "key111": { ... },
  "key222": { ... }
}
```

Comment: Ok frank that first example seems like a good solution. Would it be better to using the padding method with say 7 chars e.g. 0000001 or use the index method i have thought of (commented on dougs answer) ... The main benefit I can see with yours is sending less data in the keys as the push() will contain more data.